# Make another entity from entity by Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables, user and userAttr.

'user' and 'userAttr' are tied as onebyone.

I would like to insert a row in userAttr when row is inserted user.

So this is my idea.

Make new data row of userAttr In prePersist() method in user entity.

in Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

```
class User extends BaseUser implements ParticipantInterface
{
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $userAttr = new userAttr();
        $userAttr->setUser($this);

        $userAttr->setEnabled(true);
        $this->setUserAttr($userAttr);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($userAttr);
        $em->flush();
```

but it shows error like this.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User::getDoctrine() in
```

There are two quesions.

1.Is my basic idea correct?

2.How can I get the instance of doctrine in entity class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you got a little fallacy in there. Once the entity manager persists a entry it will also persist the related one-to-one connection. So if you persist *$userAttr* - which is one-to-one connected to your instance of *User* - it will persist User *before* it should get persisted. Causing double writings in the database. You can avoid this by adjusting your prePersist() to

```
public function prePersist()
{
    $userAttr = new userAttr();
    $userAttr->setUser($this);

    $userAttr->setEnabled(true);
    $this->setUserAttr($userAttr);
}
```

This avoids finding a way to get a instance of the entity manager too.

Comment: Your way enable me to make two rows at the same time. it's great and suit for my purpose. another answer says its not good way  though.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your second question first.

### How can I get the instance of doctrine in entity class?

You can't and you shouldn't. Your entity class is just a model, it has no knowledge of **Doctrine**, **Symfony** or the **Entity Manager**. Persistence will be handled at a higher level.

### Is my basic idea correct?

No. As I said in the previous point, persistence shouldn't be a worry at this level. Here, you're just defining the properties and relations of your model.

I imagine your entity looks somewhat like this:

```
class User extends BaseUser implements ParticipantInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserAttr", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $userAttr;

    public function setUserAttr(UserAttr $userAttr = null)
    {
        $this->userAttr = $userAttr;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserAttr()
    {
        return $this->technician;
    }
}
```

Note the `cascade={"persist"}` option in the relation with `UserAttr`. This is what tells **Doctrine** that it should insert that into the database, too.

### Further reading

[Doctrine: One-To-One, Unidirectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional)

[Doctrine: Transitive persistence / Cascade Operations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

[Symfony: Persisting Objects to the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database)

Comment: Your answer is quite clear. thanks. this sample code is almost the same as mine. I add cascade={"persist"}.

Comment: However when I inserted row in user table. Nothing happened on userAttr table. Is it possible to insert a row in userAttr automatically when I insert a row in user table? I should write another code when I insert the row in user table? (your 'higer level' means this?)

Comment: No. It means you should write something like what @spekulatius told you on a controller. The `cascade={"persist"}` means you don't have to `persist()` and `flush()` `userAtrr`.